# how can I balance these brackets in this recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive Python function to get all of the successive 1 or 2 digit orderings from a given number.  For example, given `123`, the result would be: `[[1, 2, 3], [12, 3], [1, 23]]`.

I've written a function that seems to be on the right track but I can't balance the brackets.

```
def gen_codes(num):

    if len(str(num)) == 1:
        return [[num]]
    result = []
    for i in range(1, 3):
        rest_str = str(num)[i:]
        path = [int(str(num)[0:i])]
        if len(rest_str):            
            path = [path + x for x in gen_codes(int(rest_str))]
        result.append(path)
    return result

print(gen_codes(123))
```

This outputs:

```
[[[1, [2, 3]], [1, 23]], [[12, 3]]]
```

Expected:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [12, 3], [1, 23]]
```

Comment: What does "balance brackets" mean?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq  I wrote what the result should be and what I'm getting

Comment: is it that there can be more than 3 lists?

Comment: @AnnZen  It should work for any number.  123 is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
path = [path + x for x in gen_codes(int(rest_str))]
```

as it is adding an extra level of nesting of the lists. You should replace this code:

```
if len(rest_str):            
    path = [path + x for x in gen_codes(int(rest_str))]
result.append(path)
```

with

```
if len(rest_str):
    for x in gen_codes(int(rest_str)):
        result.append(path + x)
else:
    result.append(path)
```

and then your code will produce the desired results. For example:

```
print(gen_codes(123))
print(gen_codes(1234))
print(gen_codes(12345))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 23], [12, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 34], [1, 23, 4], [12, 3, 4], [12, 34]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 45], [1, 2, 34, 5], [1, 23, 4, 5], [1, 23, 45], [12, 3, 4, 5], [12, 3, 45], [12, 34, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably far more performant ways to write this, but here is the first one I thought of:

```
def f(s: str) -> List[List[int]]:
    if len(s) == 1:
        return [[int(s)]]
    if len(s) == 2:
        return [[int(s[0]), int(s[1])], [int(s)]]
    return (
        [[int(s[0]), *xs] for xs in f(s[1:])] +
        [[int(s[0:2]), *xs] for xs in f(s[2:])]
    )
```

*Two* base cases:

- if `s == "a"`, return `[a]`
- if `s == "ab"`, return `[a, b]` and `[ab]`

For all other strings,

- if `s == "ab[...]"`, return `[a, *xs] for xs in f(b[...])` and `[ab, *xs] for xs in f([...])`

One key idea is to consistently operate within the correct (monadic) context. And that is always `List[List[int]]`. If you ever return anything else, you're doing something wrong.